# How to make a filter where i can get a range of employees

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, db2, range

We use a third party software that use SQL queries.

I need to make a filter(every time I run this filter it triggers a sql statement). I need to set up different filters for different people. All our clients are divided into 3 groups.
Group 1 names starting from A-G
Group 2  H-P
Group 3 Q-z

I need to set it up in such a way that Somebody dealing with group 1 only sees clients with names starting from A to G.

Comment: We're going to need more. Specifically: How are the users accessing the information?  Is there a table which tracks users associated to groups? is there a table which defines groups and limits?  we can make assumptions and guesses but with the information provided so far I can't see how we can answer this question.  You need to be specific about the problem providing sample data, existing queries and what you're not able to accomplish.  As your question is written its too vague.  I'm not making fun; trying to provide constructive advice so you get the help you want.

Comment: @All - No need to down-vote the question. User clearly states he is new and not experienced and asking for help... So, do provide help instead of trying to look smart...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work -- can't test in DB2, but I believe it supports `LEFT`:

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE LEFT(GROUP1NAME,1) <= 'G';
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE LEFT(GROUP1NAME,1) >= 'H' AND LEFT(GROUP1NAME,1) <= 'P';
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE LEFT(GROUP1NAME,1) >= 'Q';
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db217/2).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create views, not some SQL filters. I do not know what SQL you are using but try reading about the views and their usage one of which is "Provide additional level of table security by restricting access to a set of rows or columns of a table..."